# How to use yield in python to defer evaluation in a conditional statement?

Tags: python, conditional-statements, yield

I wish to use yield inside an if statement to defer evaluation of a callback function. If I do the following:

```
def callback(): 
    print "hi yield"

class dicTest(): 
    e = {}

    def eval(self): 
        yield callback()
```

and call:

```
d = dicTest() 
gen = d.eval()
gen.next() 
gen = d.eval() 
gen.next() 
gen.next()
```

Then the last gen.next() generates the exception, as expected. However, I need to do this:

```
def callback(): 
    print "hi yield"

class dicTest(): 
    e = {}

    def eval(self, cond): 
        if cond: 
            print "eval true"
        else: 
            yield callback()
```

The test is below:

```
d = dicTest() 
cond = True 
gen = d.eval(cond)
print "next eval" 
gen.next() 
print "next cond"
cond = False 
print "next eval false"
gen = d.eval(cond) 
gen.next() 
gen.next()
```

result from the test:

```
next eval
eval true
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "little.py", line 43, in <module>
    gen.next() 
StopIteration
```

Why does this generates an exception? How to fix this?

Comment: Could you not separate your inputs and the outputs, so we can make sense of what happened and when?

Comment: Is this your real code? Could it have something to do with the fact that your dict is a shared class attribute instead of an instance variable, which you almost never want to do? Your "test" with your second example code should raise `StopIteration` on the first `gen.next()` because you just `print` and `yield` nothing.

Comment: What are you expecting instead of that? what do you want it to return instead?

Comment: I don't think this is really a great use of `yield`.  Why don't you just *return* the callback function itself and let the caller call it?

Comment: If you don't want to evaluate callback yet, you should return `callback`, the function, not `callback()`, the function value, but I probably don't understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstood how `yield` works. `yield` returns a value but saves the state of the generator. So the next time you call `gen.next()` the generator will pick up where it left off.

In your case when `cond` is true you print something but never actually yield a value. I think what you want is:

```
if cond: 
    print "eval true"
    yield "" # Some dummy value
yield callback()
```

Note that here when `cond` is true there is an additional `yield` before the callback. The generator will have to call `next` one more time in order to consume that first `yield` and get to the callback.